# how to use boilerpipe with a local html file?

Tags: java, html-content-extraction, boilerpipe

I have an html file on my local disk and would like to extract text from it using BoilerPipe.

The "getText" method from the class ExtractorBase accepts a reader, so I wrote:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/myHTMLfile");
System.out.println(ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(fr));
```

But then I get an error pointing to this second line of code.

Any clue? Thx!

EDIT: the whole error msg is:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cyberneko/html/HTMLConfiguration
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeHTMLParser.<init>(BoilerpipeHTMLParser.java:50)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeHTMLParser.<init>(BoilerpipeHTMLParser.java:41)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:51)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:69)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:101)
    at neuromarket.BoilerPlateExtractor.run(BoilerPlateExtractor.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 9 more
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cyberneko/html/HTMLConfiguration
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeHTMLParser.<init>(BoilerpipeHTMLParser.java:50)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeHTMLParser.<init>(BoilerpipeHTMLParser.java:41)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:51)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:69)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:101)
    at neuromarket.BoilerPlateExtractor.run(BoilerPlateExtractor.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add [nekohtml-1.x.x.jar](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net) at classpath.